# Automatic URL rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

At first I used IIS server for PHP, so I'm new to Apache (Windows platform). I am in some puzzle related with URL rewrite. As in my .htaccess file I use the below code for URL Rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.aspx$ $1.php [nc]
```

Now If I browse a .php page with .aspx extension, it works well.  eg If I browse

**www.example.com/guwahati.php  =>  www.example.com/guwahati.aspx (both URL works.)**

But I want it automatically. Like if I type www.example.com/guwahati.php, it will automatically convert to www.example.com/guwahati.aspx, is it possible ? also URL rewritting is not working on my localhost. may anyone help me please.

Comment: Your example changes an _incoming_ *.aspx _to_ *.php (because presumably your actual script is PHP). If you wanted to change an incoming .php to .aspx it would be possible by simply swapping aspx and php. However, you probably can't do both, as it would do one and then the other, possibly getting you into a loop. Also, make up your mind whether or not it's working -- you said "it works well", and then you say "is not working" -- are these on two different servers? If so, the "localhost" isn't configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want it automatically. Like if I type www.example.com/guwahati.php, it will automatically cconvert to www.example.com/guwahati.aspx, is it possible ?

It is possible, but by using redirect headers, not URL rewrites. Actually you could do an URL rewrite that redirects to a single file that replaces the target extension with aspx and then redirects to it. You may need to enable `mod_rewrite` in order for it to work.

Comment: Thank you, at least I got the Idea. But may you tell me why url rewrite is not working on my localhost ?

Comment: @Indian Girl: Have you checked if its enabled?

Comment: I have run phpinfo() command, but not found mod_rewrite anywhere, just found mod_ssl. Where I can turn on ?

Comment: @Indian Girl: Check your `httpd.conf` for a line reading 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so', make sure there is no # at the beginning or otherwise the line its a comment. Restart apache for changes to have effect.